# Equivalent of bash's Ctrl-r in PowerShell

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, history

does anybody knows of a way to have the backward command search feature of bash `[Ctrl-r]` (and `[Ctrl-o]`) that are so useful, in windows powershell ?

`C-r` is a more powerful `arrow up` history manipulation, it is like emacs's `C-r` in that it searches backward inside the commands you previously entered. Then `C-o` executes that command and immediately places on the line the next command after that. So that you can repeat passed series of commands efficiently. Also it looks up into a saved history, not a session history. (`~/.bash_history` file). Which is infinitely useful.

thanks.

ps: as a bonus the tab completion not working by cycles would be awsome also.

Comment: What does ctrl O do that you want to replicate? More info us always good...

Comment: Yep, edited the question :)

Comment: I don't know what saved history and session history means. I've used bash before but I never got deeply into it. You have to remember that many of the people that could potentially answer your question may not be familiar with bash.

Comment: Sure, the session history is what we have typically in windows, you start a cmd or a powershell and hit `up` key, nothing comes up, type a command, validate, then on the next prompt you can hit `up` and your previous commands is set on the prompt. A saved history would let you hit `up` and recall commands you entered in previous session (across runs of the console), maybe many weeks before even.

Comment: I don't believe that this feature is supported. PowerShell 3 does have a hook called `PSConsoleHostReadline` that could be useful. A good place to start would be to use [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine), which uses that hook. PSReadLine doesn't support ctrl-o, but it does support ctrl-r (supposedly -- it didn't work for me). I may have a look at implementing ctrl-o over Christmas because it does sound useful.

Comment: Ah, PSReadLine, this seems like my answer, you should post it as an answer. it does not have C-o but it has C-r which is the most important. It also has the tab completion tweak that I wanted in bonus.

Comment: Ok I tested PSReadLine, the behavior is weird for the ctrl+r because it searches only AFTER having typed something. well better than nothing. and the Tab complete is perfect. I also realized there is no Ctrl-k (cut line from cursor position) shortcut ?

Comment: If you execute `Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler`, you can see the key bindings. Delete-to-the-end is ctrl-end. You can change that if you like. One thing I like about PSReadLine, by the way, is that it has unix rather than cmd.exe command history. In cmd.exe, if you press up or down-arrow, it's like you are moving a pointer in a list, so if you execute something halfway along the list, then press down-arrow, it will show you the next thing in the list. I find that confusing.

Comment: If you reply to me, by the way, you should say @dangph so that I get notified. (I don't need to do that here because I am replying to your post, so you get notified anyway.)

Comment: PSReadline author here - @v.oddou - Ctrl+K should be bound to KillLine in Emacs mode.  Ctrl+R should work w/ or w/o typing something first.  I'm happy to add Ctrl+O - feel free to open an issue on github.

Answer (score 17):

Type first letters of the command and press <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Alternatively you can press <kbd>F7</kbd> and type first letters.

More details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff678293.aspx

Comment: F7 does nothing...

Comment: Could you provide more information? May be it could be useful for others. Which version of Powershell and which version of Windows?

The default Powershell is quite limited. It's better to use MobaXterm or ConEmuMaximus 5 to get better UX

Comment: @CatBoss F7 works in cmd

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc then the answer needs to say so, because the question is about Powershell....

Comment: See the answer below - don't waste your time with F8 if you are on powershell 5+

Answer (score 9):

[WMF 5.0 RTM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395), which includes [Windows PowerShell 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-with-powershell), now supports the same reverse command search feature of bash `CTRL+R`. I have been using this in Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, and my *bash muscle memory* is very happy.

The support actually comes from the PowerShell module [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) which I see was mentioned in some of the comments of the question. The good thing is that PSReadLine now appears to be *included in the base WMF 5.0 installation*, at least it is on Windows 10.

If you are running PowerShell 3 or later, you can also [install PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine#installation) as well and get the history search feature.

**Note:** I've not found out how to get this working in ISE as `CTRL+R` is mapped to something else (Show/Hide Script Pane).

Answer (score 5):

To manipulate your history you may use the history cmdlets, list them by this command:

```
Get-Command *-history
```

Searching your history is done like this, feel free to make a function to shorten it:

```
Get-history | Select-String "command"

function f ($Name) { Get-history | Select-String $name }
```